# Deep linking Facebook android / ios issue

Tags: android, ios, facebook, deep-linking

I wan to create a deep link that opens the facebook app. But I noticed that the link is different from ios and android. iOS triggers `fb://profile` and android `fb://page`.

How can I manage that the app will open correctly on both devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Deep linking` is supposed to be done for your own app. Even though you use anyone of those links you can open your own app when these links are fired in browser. Even you don't have control when that link is opened in browzer. i.e. User will be shown the number of options for opening that link for those apps who have registered for that link in their `intent filter`.

If you want to open facebook app then use `Intents` for that.

Comment: Oke thnx I will try that!